# PE file rebase fail

Tags: c, windows, winapi, portable-executable

Here is my problem.

I'm working on a packer. This packer can run a program from memory. Actually, this part works. But sometimes VirtualAllocEx return Invalid address because there is not enough continuous space for the program (the program is an executable PE x86 file.

It s embedded as a resource of the packer). So I need to rebase/reallocate/Fixeup/whatever the name you are using for that :) . But it doesn't work. The PerformeRebase methods fail.

here I get the offset it's ok : 0x16000 (the same as if I open my pe file in a pe explorer program)

DWORD dwVa = pPE->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress;

here I have a size : 3564 it's ok

DWORD dwCb = pPE->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].Size;

But here in pBR , VirtualAddress = 0 and SizeOfBlock = 0 So there is a problem, because there is a section .reloc , I see it in the pe explorer program.

PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION pBR = MakePtr(PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION, lpAddress, dwVa);

So I'm wondering why it doesn't work, is it because I copy the section after the call of this method ? if it is the case , I don't understand in what order I have to do it, I'm a little bit confuse in all that addresses.

Here is the code :

rebase :

```
#define MakePtr( cast, ptr, addValue ) (cast)( (DWORD)(ptr) + (addValue) )

BOOL PerformRebase(LPVOID lpAddress, DWORD dwNewBase)
{

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpAddress;

    if (pDH->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return FALSE;

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pPE = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char *)pDH + pDH->e_lfanew);

    if (pPE->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return FALSE;



    DWORD dwDelta = dwNewBase - pPE->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

    DWORD dwVa = pPE->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress;
    DWORD dwCb = pPE->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].Size;

    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION pBR = MakePtr(PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION, lpAddress, dwVa);

    UINT c = 0;

    while (c < dwCb)
    {

        c += pBR->SizeOfBlock;

        int RelocCount = (pBR->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);

        LPVOID lpvBase = MakePtr(LPVOID, lpAddress, pBR->VirtualAddress);

        WORD *areloc = MakePtr(LPWORD, pBR, sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION));


        for (int i = 0; i < RelocCount; i++)

        {

            int type = areloc[i] >> 12;

            if (type == IMAGE_REL_BASED_ABSOLUTE)
                continue;

            if (type != IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            int ofs = areloc[i] & 0x0fff;

            DWORD *pReloc = MakePtr(DWORD *, lpvBase, ofs);

            if (*pReloc - pPE->OptionalHeader.ImageBase > pPE->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            *pReloc += dwDelta;

        }

        pBR = MakePtr(PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION, pBR, pBR->SizeOfBlock);

    }

    pPE->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = dwNewBase;

    return TRUE;
}
```

And the run methode :

```
BOOL WINAPI Run(LPVOID pImage, char* pPath)
{
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pim;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
    STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
    CONTEXT pContext;

    DWORD dwSectionCount;
    DWORD dwImageSize;

    memcpy(&IDH, pImage, sizeof(IDH));
    memcpy(&INH, (void*)((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew), sizeof(INH));


    /* Sanity check : see if MZ */
    if (IDH.e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (INH.Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    memset(&peStartUpInformation, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    memset(&peProcessInformation, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    memset(&pContext, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));

    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ntdll.dll");

    PGNSI pGNSI;
    WVM pWVM;
    int re;

    pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtUnmapViewOfSection");
    pWVM = (WVM) GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtWriteVirtualMemory");

    void* newImageBase;

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL,
        &peStartUpInformation, &peProcessInformation))
    {
        //re = pGNSI(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (DWORD*)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase);
        if ((newImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (DWORD*)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase, INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)) == 0)
        {


            if ((newImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess, NULL, INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)) == 0)
            {
                FreeLibrary(hModule);
                TerminateProcess(peProcessInformation.hProcess, 1);
                int i = GetLastError();
                printf("GLE : %d", i);
                Sleep(5000);
                Run(pImage, pPath);
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                //pim = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew);
                //pe_perform_base_reloc((char*)pImage, pim, (unsigned long)((char*)newImageBase - INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase));
                PerformRebase(pImage, (DWORD)newImageBase);
            }
        }

        re = pWVM(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (DWORD*)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase
            , pImage, INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, 0);

        for (dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
        {
            memcpy(&section
                , (void*)((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * dwSectionCount))
                , sizeof(section));

            re = pWVM(peProcessInformation.hProcess
                , (DWORD*)(INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + section.VirtualAddress)
                ,(char*)pImage + section.PointerToRawData, section.SizeOfRawData,0);
        }

        pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
        GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);

        BOOL res = WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,
            (void*)(pContext.Ebx + 8), &(INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0);
        pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);
        ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);

        WaitForSingleObject(peProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(peProcessInformation.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(peProcessInformation.hThread);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I know that the code is not that proper, i'm in sandbox mode here ^^

Thanks in advance for your adivces.

Comment: Sorry for the editing mess, I added a couple tags (more importantly the language tag so your post reaches more people).

Comment: Probably this program has a reloc section but without reloc data. Besides, I believe there's other work needed to be done to make the actual program fly.

Comment: Probably it is a file with reloc section but without reloc data.